# Install-Module -Name newtonsoft.json - works until I close and re-open ISE

Tags: powershell, json.net

In PowerShell 5.1, I ran this:

```
Install-Module -Name newtonsoft.json
```

and I was able to use the library in this statement:

```
$jsonText = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlDoc)
```

Then I closed PowerShell, and ran same script, and it failed.

```
Unable to find type [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert].
```

If I do "`Get-InstalledModule`" then newtonsoft.json shows up on the list (1.0.2.201).

Now, even if I run the Install command again, it still gets the error above.

Maybe I'm digging myself deeper into a hole, but I tried this:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json\1.0.2.201\libs\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
```

and now it gives error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert] does not contain a method named 'SerializeXmlNode'.
```

Does the "Install-Module" to add it permanently?  It created a directory: `c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Install-Module` once and then in your scripts use `Import-Module`  :

```
Import-Module newtonsoft.json
```

You will find more information in [About-Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-5.1).